# How to prove that there exist infinitely $(m,n)$ such $[n\sqrt{p}]=\frac{1}{2}(3m^2-m)$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that: for any prime number $p$, there are infinitely many pairs of positive integers  $(m, n)$ such that
>   $$[n\sqrt{p}]=\dfrac{3m^2-m}{2}$$
>   where $[x]$ is the largest integer not greater than $x$

Here’s my idea:

Assume that $p=2$, then 
$$[\sqrt{2}n]=\dfrac{3m^2-m}{2}$$
then it is clear that for $m=n=1$ is such it, and we don't find infinitely many pairs $(m,n)$.

Assume that $p=3$, and 
$$[\sqrt{3}n]=\dfrac{3m^2-m}{2}$$
we let $m=n=1$ and we also don't find infinitely many pairs $(m,n)$.

But for an arbitrary $p$, I can't prove it. Can you help me ?

Comment: For $p=2$, why is it clear there are infinitely many pairs $m,n$?

Comment: sorry, i have only find one pairs

Answer (score 3):

It may be overkill, but here is a proof using the [van der Corput difference theorem.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanderCorputsTheorem.html) It at least has the advantage of showing that the long-term proportion of $m$'s for which such an $n$ exists is $1/\sqrt{p}$.

The equation is easily shown to be equivalent to the inequality
$$n -\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}} < u_m \leq n, \qquad \text{ where } u_m = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p}}(3m^2 - m).$$

Thus the problem amounts to showing that the sequence $u_m$ takes values modulo 1 in the interval $(1-1/\sqrt{p},1]$ infinitely often. For this, it is sufficient to show that the sequence is [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) modulo 1.

By van der Corput's theorem, it is enough to show this for the sequence
$$v_m = u_{m + h} - u_m = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p}}(3h^2 - h) + \frac{3h}{2\sqrt{p}} m$$
for any integer $h > 0$. But this is an arithmetic sequence with irrational step, so the result is well-known in this case.